# foreach on unknown type

Tags: c#, foreach

I need to be able to loop around an unknown type for example

```
  foreach (var test in viewData["foobar"])
  {
  }
```

Any suggestions

Comment: C# I presume? Might be worth to tell which language you're developing in...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to at least cast `viewData["foobar"]` to `IEnumerable` to have `object`s in your `test` variable.

The cast may fail, so you'll first have to check whether `viewData["foobar"]` actually implements `IEnumerable` with `is` or `as` operator:

```
if(viewData["foobar"] is IEnumerable)
    foreach(var test in (IEnumerable)viewData["foobar"])
```

Note that this is using `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, not `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: viewData["foobar"] might already be an IEnumerable if viewData's named indexer returns a type (derived from) IEnumerable.

Comment: That's System.Collections.IEnumerable, not System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>.

Answer (score 0):

If `viewData["foobar"]` is of the type object, then you can't iterate over it. The only way to iterate with a foreach loop is on IEnumerator derived types.